# How to open a file of any length in C?

Tags: c, file-io, fopen, fgets

As a school assignment I'm tasked with writing a program that opens any text file and performs a number of operations on the text. The text must be loaded using a linked list, meaning an array of structs containing the char pointer and the pointer to the next struct. One line per struct.

But I'm having problems actually loading the file. It seems the memory required to load the text into memory must be allocated before I actually read the text. Hence I have to open the file several times. Once to count the number of lines, then twice per line; once to count the characters in the line then once to read them. It seems absurd to open a file hundreds of times just to read it into memory.

Obviously there are better ways of doing this, I just don't know them :-)

*Examples*

- *Can the point from which `fgetc` fetches a character be moved without re-opening the file?*
- *Can the number of lines or characters in a file be checked before it is "opened"?*
- *Can I somehow read a line or string from a file and save it to memory without allocating a fixed amount of bytes?*
- *etc*

Comment: You might want to take a look at `fseek`, `rewind` and `ftell`.

Comment: Err...a linked list is not an array and while it can be implemented *on* an array that is not the usual way to accomplish it in c.

Comment: good questions.  post your code and then people can comment more directly.

Comment: Add to Paul's list `getline` (which is not part of the standard library, but is in POSIX).

Comment: @dmckee: I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~rjp/Coursewww/Cwww/linklist.html) when it comes to linked lists. It shows an array of struct instances linked to each other. I may be misusing the word **array** though, but I figure it's ok since C has no such thing as an array anyway.

Comment: @Randy: There is no code yet :-) This question is strictly theoretical.

Comment: You might prefer *"collection"* of structures because *"array"* has a specific meaning in c and derived languages, and yes c has arrays (`int ary[10]`...) though they are rather bare and feature free by comparison to those in some other languages.

Comment: But that's not really an array is it? It's just a stack equivalent of the statement `int* ary = malloc(sizeof(int)*10)`. At least our teacher has drilled it into our heads that "**C HAS NO ARRAYS**" since most of us just learned Java last year and have unrealistic expectations of C.

Comment: Your teacher is being overly pedantic. The is a very real distinction between arrays and pointers (just look at the hugely duplicated set of questions on passing multidimensional arrays in c) and they are not always interchangeable. In particular the compiler knows how big `int ary[10]` is but does *not* know how big `int *ary=malloc(10*sizeof int)` is. What c arrays don't do is carry their own length with them (which makes passing them to functions different than in some other languages), nor perform any bounds checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to open the file more than once, nor to pass through it more than once.

Look at the POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) function.  It reads lines into allocated space.  You can use it to read the lines, and then copy the results for your linked list.

There is no need with a linked list to know how many lines there are ahead of time; that's an advantage of lists.

So, the code can be done with a single pass.  Even if you can't use `getline()`, you can use `fgets()` and monitor whether it reads to end of line each time, and if it doesn't you can allocate (and reallocate) space to hold the line as needed (`malloc()`, `realloc()` and eventually `free()` from `<stdlib.h>`).

Your specific questions are largely immaterial if you adopt anything of the approach I suggest, but:

- Using `fseek()` (and in extremis `rewind()`) will move the read pointer (for `fgetc()` and all other functions), unless the 'file' does not support seeking (eg, a pipe provided as standard input).
- Characters can be determined with `stat()` or `fstat()` or variants.  Lines cannot be determined except by reading the file.
- Since the file could be from zero bytes to gigabytes in size, there isn't a sensible way of doing fixed size allocations.  You are pretty much forced into dynamic memory allocation with `malloc()` et al.  (Behind the scenes, `getline()` uses `malloc()` and `realloc()`.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot count the number of lines in a file without actually traversing it. You could get the total file size, but that's not whats intended here. The idea of using a linked list of lines is that you operate on the file one line at a time. You do not need to read anything in advance. While you haven't read the whole file, read a line, add it to its own node at the end of the linked list, move to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question: you can change the position in the file you are reading from with the fseek() function.

There are several ways you could do this. For example, you could have a fixed-size buffer, fill it with bytes from the file, copy lines from the buffer to the list, fill the buffer again and so on.